# Insert Button After 1 Paragraph Only If 2 or More Paragraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

if ( $('p').length < 1 ) { 

$('p:last-child').after('<div id="toggle" class="btn">Read More</div>');

$('p').not('.entry-content p:first-child').wrap('<div class="text" />');  

}

$("#toggle").click(function() {

    var elem = $("#toggle").text();

    if (elem == "Read More") {

      $("#toggle").text("Read Less");
      $("#text").slideDown("slow");

    } else {

      $("#toggle").text("Read More");
      $("#text").slideUp("fast");
    }

  }); });



<p>This is an example of a post, you could edit this to put information about yourself or your site so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with your readers what is on your mind.</p>

<p>This is an example of a post, you could edit this to put information about yourself or your site so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with your readers what is on your mind.</p>

<p>This is an example of a post, you could edit this to put information about yourself or your site so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with your readers what is on your mind.</p>
```

I only want to add the button after the first paragraph if there's 2 or more paragraphs.

The jQuery adds the button after the 1st paragraph. I don't want it added if there's only 1 paragraph of text in each article. I only want it added when there's at least 2 paragraphs.

Update : Basically, if there's only 1 paragraph, i don't need any of the jQuery to run so i guess i simply need a conditional.

Update 2 :  Like this but for paragraphs http://jsfiddle.net/RyqJ9/

Comment: You should wrap your paragraph inside a `<div>`.

Comment: Your question as well HTML is not clear.Please clarify it

Comment: The jQuery adds the button after the 1st paragraph. I don't want it added if there's only i paragraph. I only want it added when there's at least 2 paragraphs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check for condition for each of the text div with `$(".text").each(function()` with `if((textBox.find('p').length)>1)` so that if there are two or more `p` then you will show the button for that text div

Here is a sample code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".content .entry-content").each(function(){
  var contentBox = $(this);
  if (contentBox.find('p').length > 1){ 
    var lastOne = contentBox.find('p').length - 1;
    contentBox.append('<div id="toggle" class="btn">Read More</div>');
    $('.content .entry-content p').not('.entry-content p:first-child').wrap('<div class="text" />');  
    contentBox.find(".text").hide();
    contentBox.find(".btn").click(function(){
      if($(this).attr('class').indexOf('btnDown')==-1){
        contentBox.find(".text").slideDown("slow");
        $(this).addClass("btnDown");
        $(this).html("Read Less");
      }else{
        contentBox.find(".text").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).removeClass("btnDown");
        $(this).html("Read More");
      }
    });
  }
});
});
```

```css
.text{
  background-color:green;
  margin:5px 0;
}
.btn{
  background-color:red;
}
.content{
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<div class="entry-content">
<p>This is an example of a post, you could edit this to put information about yourself or your site so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with your readers what is on your mind.</p>

<p>This is an example of a post, you could edit this to put information about yourself or your site so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with your readers what is on your mind.</p>

<p>This is an example of a post, you could edit this to put information about yourself or your site so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with your readers what is on your mind.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
<div class="entry-content">
<p>This is an example of a post, you could edit this to put information about yourself or your site so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with your readers what is on your mind.</p>

<p>This is an example of a post, you could edit this to put information about yourself or your site so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with your readers what is on your mind.</p>

<p>This is an example of a post, you could edit this to put information about yourself or your site so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with your readers what is on your mind.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
<div class="entry-content">
<p>This is an example of a post, you could edit this to put information about yourself or your site so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with your readers what is on your mind.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: See update. I don't think i need all this when i only need to run the jQuery if there's more than 1 paragraph.

Comment: ok. I updated my answer. I am now using css to first hide the button. and jquery will check only one condition if there are more than one text div and then only run any further.

Comment: There will never be more than 1 text div. Its paragraphs i want to check for.

Comment: I updated my answer. checking the fiddle now. see if I'm missing anything

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize my mistake until I added one more div. please check now. I think it's working good. Let me know if this was not what you wanted.

Comment: The jQuery only inserts 1 text div after the 1st paragraph. I don't want it inserted if there's only 1 paragraph. See my code.

Comment: oh. lol, then you can remove that `each()` and make that work. it won't cause harm either if you leave it as it. but the rest of it works fine right?

Comment: No. You have added the text div wrong. Look at my jQuery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155565/discussion-between-ab29007-and-dev).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this (untested)? Or if you're trying to append it to the bottom of the paragraph, rather than after it, use `append()` instead of `after()`.

```
$(function($) {
  if($('p:nth-child(2)').length) {
    $('p:first-child').after('<div id="toggle" class="btn">Read More</div>');
  }
});
```